# ¿Por qué no se exporta un .jsp a excel en Chrome y Edge?

Tags: java, jsp

he de exportar varios .jsp que contienen tablas con datos a excel, al pulsar un botón.
En la primera linea del jsp tengo:

```
      <%@ page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel" import="java.util.*%>
```

En IE y Firefox funciona, pero en los otros navegadores no. He probado a sustituir el contentType por:

```
      application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Pero sigue igual. ¿alguna recomendación? 
Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre en Chrome?

Comment: Se descarga el archivo en formato jsp con la estructura html. Necesito que se abra en excel, como lo hace en el IE

Answer (score 1):

carga el sitio en el navegador edge  y despues ve a Configuración y mas ( ícono de 3 puntitos en la parte superior derecha) y eliges Cargar en Modo Internet Explorer.
Y prueba la ejecución de la página.
Saludos